# Some internet services do not work when using my phone hotspot

Tags: networking, internet, ipv6, hot-spot

I have a problem on Ubuntu 20.04.03

When connecting to the wifi through my phone hotspot some internet services such as Slack, Gmail or even Netflix, Prime video do not work. They either do not load, tell me their is a user problem or tell me there is a connection problem. Meanwhile, most websites such as Google and YouTube work flawlessly.

This is quite an inconvenience since I'm always on the move and using the 4G from my phone to work most of the time.

This problem does not happen when I connect to an actual internet box like the one I have at home.

I suspect it might be related to me disabling ipv6 on my computer a while ago to access a server. I've tried enabling it by modifying the sysctl.config file and adding

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
```

but I'm not sure it has worked as nothing shows up as inet6 when doing `ip a`.

It is my hypothesis for the problem because I know that the Network protocol my phone uses is IPV6 (I can't change it) but I'm really not sure.

I've tried disabling the firewall `ufw` but nothing happened.

Please if anybody has some ideas, please share them with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to fix this issue would be to connect via VPN (with your phone).

To me it sounds like a localization issue. I had this back in the days when i was using hybrid-connection (DSL-Lite and LTE/4G). Using a VPN fixed that issue for me.

Comment: It seems to be working ! Thank you very much. I guess I'll have to renew my vpn subscription. Not the greatest fix but it's a fix.